# Setting the onClick property dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the onClick property of a dynamically generated div in a loop but the code below is not working beyond generating the divs. Can someone please help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gengrid()
      {
          var i=0;
          var num_stud=8;
          var newdiv;
          var divIdName;
          var maindiv;
          for(i=1;i<=num_stud;i++)
          {
             newdiv = document.createElement('div');
             divIdName = '50'+i;
             newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
             newdiv.onClick= function(){addit(i);};
             newdiv.innerHTML = '<img src=50'+i+'.jpg alt="a"></img>';
             maindiv=document.getElementById('main');
             maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
          }
      }
   gengrid();
   function addit(picno)
      {
          alert(picno+'');
       } 
  </script>
```

Comment: Try `newdiv.onclick` with `simple c`.

Comment: Small case c works , thankyou

Comment: now it always alerts you `9` , right?

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` method should have a lowercase c.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MTpUV/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gengrid()
      {
          var i=0;
          var num_stud=8;
          var newdiv;
          var divIdName;
          var maindiv;
          for(i=1;i<=num_stud;i++)
          {
             newdiv = document.createElement('div');
             divIdName = '50'+i;
             newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
             newdiv.onclick= function(){addit(i);};
             newdiv.innerHTML = '<img src=50'+i+'.jpg alt="a"></img>';
             maindiv=document.getElementById('main');
             maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
          }
      }
   gengrid();
   function addit(picno)
      {
          alert(picno+'');
       } 
  </script>
```